# Check the properties/behaviors of Service and Operation Contract

Tags: wcf

What is the method of knowing the properties/behaviors of Operations and Services Programmatically.

For example: From an operation I would like to print the AddressFilterMode, ConcurrencyMode etc. of the service, and Impersonation, TransactionAutoComplete, etc. properties of Operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain get `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` and `DispatchOperation` instances and use their properties.

```
var serviceBehavior = OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();

var operations = OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations;
string currentOperationAction = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
DispatchOperation currentOperation = ( from o in operations
                                       where o.Action == currentOperationAction
                                       select o ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

That method is called [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You will get current type (the service) and you will explore its attributes => you will get for example address filter mode, concurrency  mode and instance context mode. You can do the same for operation, service contract, etc.